# Why does the service class variables persist on every new hit?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oop

I am working on the Spring Boot project. I have a controller which uses my service class. Here is the situation, in my service class I have few class variables which I use as counters, the issue is that whenever I hit my endpoint, the values of my counter variable persists for each hit, meaning if on first request counter value is 1 then on the second hit it becomes 2 so on and on.

Shouldn't the class variables get reset for each new request? I mean the service class should be new object for each request, right?

Here is essentially what I am doing.

My controller:

```
@Getmapping(path='/learningSpringBoot')
public RequestEntity<String> myMethod() {
 myServiceObject.learnSpring();
}
```

And in my service:

```
@Service public class Myservice {
private int counter;
 public void learnSpring() {
 System.out.println("counter : "+ counter);
 counter++;
 }
}
```

Please let me know if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here or absolutely missing some concept.

Comment: You want to learn about _scopes_. In Spring (and most containers), service objects are _singletons_ by default, which is much more efficient. State like `counter` shouldn't be stored locally anyway.

Comment: Though you are correct that in Spring beans are singletons by default, I wouldn't say it's "much more efficient": it takes time to hot start all these singletons during the bootstrapping process. Also, the GC is actually very good at cleaning up short-lived objects.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- could you suggest a better design? Lets say the counter is used to count the number of words in the request string.

Comment: In that case it should be a local variable, not an instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't the class variables get reset for each new request? I mean the service class should be new object for each request, right?

No, the `@Service` class is instantiated when you start your app since it's a `@Bean`.
Check out how [scopes](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes) and different [annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-repository-service) work. By default `@Service` is `@Scope("singleton")` so it does not get instantiated per-request and thus the variables are keeping their states.